# Twitter bot auto reply with image

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I have an error with a bot, it will work fine for a little bit but will return this error.. i was wondering if there is a fix for it and if this error is because of the code or because of the API.

```
Users/x/Documents/AUTOBOT/bot.js:39
    var mediaIdStr = data.media_id_string;
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'media_id_string' of undefined
at /Users/x/Documents/AUTOBOT/bot.js:39:31
at responseHandler (/Users/x/Documents/AUTOBOT/node_modules/twit/lib/oarequest.js:362:14)
at passBackControl (/Users/x/Documents/AUTOBOT/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:374:13)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/x/Documents/AUTOBOT/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:386:9)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:165:20)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
```

The bot will work for a bit then return that error once someone mentions the account with the keyword that you will see on the code..
Here is the code for the script..

```
var Twit = require('twit')
var fs = require('fs');


const dir = 'images' //Set your image folder here


var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key: 'x',
    consumer_secret: 'xx',
    access_token: 'xx',
    access_token_secret: 'xx',
    timeout_ms: 60 * 1000, // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.
})


var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);


var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', {
    track: '@dogarchiver dog'
})

stream.on('tweet', function(tweet) {
    var file = dir + "/" + files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)];

    var id = tweet['id_str'];
    var name = tweet['user']['screen_name'];
    var b64content = fs.readFileSync(file, {
        encoding: 'base64'
    })

    // first we must post the media to Twitter
    T.post('media/upload', {
        media_data: b64content
    }, function(err, data, response) {
        // now we can assign alt text to the media, for use by screen readers and
        // other text-based presentations and interpreters
        var mediaIdStr = data.media_id_string;

        var altText = ".."
        var meta_params = {
            media_id: mediaIdStr,
            alt_text: {
                text: altText
            }
        }
        T.post('media/metadata/create', meta_params, function(err, data, response) {


            // now we can reference the media and post a tweet (media will attach to the tweet)
            var params = {
                status: '@' + name,
                media_ids: [mediaIdStr],
                in_reply_to_status_id: id
            }

            T.post('statuses/update', params, function(err, data, response) {
                console.log(data)
            })

        })
    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

An error occurred and `Twit` is telling you about it in the callback. You din't check for an error and assumed, `data` will always be an object. In case of an error, its not.

So, you need to check if an error occurred and handle it appropriately before using `data`.

```
function(err, data, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.warn("An error occurred while posting", err);
        return;
    }

    // Here you can safely access `data`
```

Comment: so it wouldn't have to do with the api or anything as it works and stop working unless you restart?

Comment: You cannot say that. There is an unhandled error. Node doesn't know what to do with it and therefore crashes. Restarting only hides the symptoms; it doesn't fix the problem